# How do I fix my sequalize connection error?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

I'm building an app with Node, Express, and MySql. I'm using MySql version 8.0. I'm using Sequelize and MySQL2 npm package to connect to my database. I have my database connection set up like this, as explained in the Sequelize docs:

config.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = new Sequelize("call_on_me", "root", "my password", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  operatorAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
})
```

And I test the connection in my server file like this:

server.js

```
const db = require("./config/config");

db.authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log("Database connected!"))
  .catch(err => console.log("Error: " + err));
```

When I start up my server, I get an error message that reads:

Error: SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

From what I understand, 8.0 is as high as it goes at the moment, so I can't find anything about upgrading from that. This leads me to believe there's some kind of error in my config connection. Am I missing something? Or am I just failing to understand something very basic that I should know about?

If there's another piece of code you'd need to look at, just let me know.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the authentication mode, so that it works like in the prior Version of mysql

add this to your my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Do this **before adding** any users.

Comment: What if I have already added users? Is there a workaround? Or do I have to uninstall then reinstall it?